# Why does this variable always return true?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to write a login script. After logging in a session variable is set, and on the main page, the isLoggedIn function is run. The problem is, that the variable $loggedIn is always returning true. Can someone help?

```
function validateUser($user)
{
    if(isset($user)){
    session_regenerate_id ();//this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user;}
}
//Validates Login
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if($_SESSION['logged'] = 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

$loggedIn = isLoggedIn();

if($loggedIn){ SHOW CONTENT FOR LOGGED IN USERS }

else { show content for users not logged in }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the *assignment operator* `=` instead of a *conditional operator* `==`.

It's supposed to be:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1)
    return true;
```

The result of an assignment `=` is the right hand side expression, which is 1, which is always true in this case. :)

Comment: thanks, that did work, but $loggedIn always prints the value "1" is there a reason for that?

Comment: Yes, because you're setting value of $loggedIn to `true` which echoes as `1` in PHP.

Comment: well i meant, even if the session variable was not set it would echo 1, but all has been fixed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

it's because you're setting $_SESSION['logged'] with the single equals.  Use a double equals instead:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if($_SESSION['logged'] == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that did work, but $loggedIn always prints the value "1" is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if($_SESSION['logged'] = 1)//assigned value '1' to $_SESSION['logged'] so in this if condition it is checking if there is any value is $_SESSION['logged'], which will be true for all the cases (valid/invalid)
        return true;
    return false;
}

$loggedIn = isLoggedIn();/those the value for $loggedIn will be always true

change the if($_SESSION['logged'] = 1) to if($_SESSION['logged'] == 1)

Answer (score 2):

**NOT THIS**   if($_SESSION['logged'] = 1)
THIS is correct ->  if($_SESSION['logged'] **==** 1)